# Laravel app not opening on given Elastic Beanstalk URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created new beanstalk environment PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.6, Apache - with default PHP sample app. It's a classic load balancer type. But for now I have made it listening only to http at port 80. No https.

After deployment default PHP sample app runs fine on beanstalk environment url(cname) provided. Sample PHP app opens and because my environment is listening to just http so in browser I get "not secure" warning as normal behaviour but my Beanstalk URL is working so far and I see PHP sample app on browser.

Now I created fresh Laravel 7.x projects on my local machine. I tested and default "/" route points to welcome Laravel page. I deployed this sample Laravel project to my environment using EB on my Mac terminal.

Deploy is successful. I change the document root to "/public" in configuration because Laravel's index in inside public folder. Environment is in green health. Now I open Beanstalk URL and I see it's just taking a minute or so then it fails to load page saying "server where this page is located isn't responding" in Safari browser.

I checked my security group and it is listening to both http and ssh.

Final note: I have been doing this for long time. This is my first time experiencing this issue. Am I missing something?

### Edit

I went inside Ec2 dashboard. I copied both Public DNS (IPv4) and IPv4 Public IP, tried accessing them in browser. It just takes time to connect and finish with "page not responding error".

My inbound rules for my security group:

```
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   -
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   -
HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   -
```

### Edit 2

Here is my access log from environment logs:

```
172.31.21.84 (103.86.57.43) - - [24/May/2020:18:34:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 278 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"
103.86.57.58 (-) - - [24/May/2020:18:37:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 230 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"
172.31.10.171 (195.154.94.244) - - [24/May/2020:18:45:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 228 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
```

I see that GET is called on / and http 301 is returned. It moved permanently. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by creating new fresh environment from eb cli in terminal using

`eb create`

Not sure why this worked but gave issue when creating environment from console dashboard.